# Подключение к HDD WD5000LPVT через терминал

Tags: hdd

Имеется винт Western Digital WD5000LPVT-08G33, доставшийся по наслдству. При подключении его к системе по usb Victoria начинает тормозить, и также смарт отказывается давать наотказ. При проверке поверхности той же самой Викторией (если вдруг он заработает нормально) начинается сущий ад, ибо всё в бэдах. Так вот: хотелось бы его как-нибудь подключить к терминалу (как я это обычно делал с сегейтами). При подключении аля сегейт, в терминал при команде приглашения идёт мусор. Пробовал разные скорости, но без толку. В интернете не нашёл практически ничего про подключение вдшек через терминал. Может кто знает как это надо правильно делать?